# Get GTFS data from ZIP file in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gtfs

I need to get gtfs data and show raw data on screen. I tried to use `gtfs-stream` module, but not sure, how to get data from it.

```
var gtfs_source = 'https://www.bkk.hu/gtfs/budapest_gtfs.zip'

request.get(gtfs_source).pipe(gtfs.enhanced()).on('data', (entity) => {
  console.log(entity)
})
```

`gtfs-utils` has a rich set of functions, but it is unable to get data from a compressed file.

Comment: Why dont you unzip the file first and then use gtfs-stram on the unzipped data?

Comment: @Aaron : I just assumed, there is a module also for this type of input.